# How to measure propagation velocity through a trace on a pcb?

Tags: pcb, measurement, trace, velocity

With a pcb in hand, how to measure the propagation velocity of a path from point A to point B, with accuracy in the picoseconds range?

Comment: First of all: do you need the time or the velocity? I guess it's the time, so: have you got an estimation from the theory? How long is the path?

Comment: See pp.11-36 in [Black Magic](http://www.amazon.ca/High-Speed-Digital-Design-Handbook/dp/0133957241)... I have to go to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this measurement, there are two well-established methods:

**TDR**

Apply a pulse input (either the rising or falling edge of a square wave), and measure the time for the edge to propagate to the far end of the trace. The delay measurement is done with an oscilloscope, and high-end oscilloscopes have TDR plug-in modules available to automate this measurement.

Key requirements for your measurement equipment is that the pulse source should have a very fast rise time, and the cables connecting it to your system under test should not slow the edge down too much. The oscilloscope must have sufficient trigger accuracy and timebase resolution to measure the arrival time with the accuracy you want.

**Group Delay**

Use a vector network analyzer (VNA) to measure the phase response of your trace. The group delay (derivative of phase with respect to frequency) gives the propagation delay through the trace at each frequency. You'll be interested in all the frequencies contained in your signal under normal use, so for digital signals that would be from some low frequency determined by your coding scheme up to a high frequency determined by the rise and fall times of your edges.

In this case the quality of the stimulus is less critical than in the TDR case, but you do need to carefully calibrate the VNA and interconnecting cables on a daily or half-daily basis, using a quality calibration kit, to be sure of getting a meaningful measurement.

**More difficulties**

If your traces are layed out as tightly-coupled differential lines, you would want to do these measurements using differential stimulus and measurement. Unfortunately, appropriate gear to do the measurements differentially is not widely available. If your traces are single-ended, or differential but layed out as uncoupled lines, then a single-ended measurement is appropriate.

Also, as Mazurnification points out in his answer, how you connect your test gear to the traces is critical. If you can arrange to test between two connectorized ends of the trace, that's the best. If you are trying to test traces between chips on a populated board, that's almost impossible. If you have an un-stuffed board, you may be able to connect to it with some kind of probes. But more likely you will just build some test coupons onto the panel with your boards that let you connectorize traces of the same geometry as the ones you are worried about.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is mainly re calculation.
 Measuring is easier :-).

Any answers you get from anyone here will only be the first step on a highly 
technical journey. The basic answer is "about 6 inches or 150 mm per nanosecond. The longer answer is ...

In free space a nanosecond is close to a light foot or about 300mm, so a picosecond is about 0.3mm & 10 picoseconds is about 3mm. The word "about" tends to feature a lot in this sort of magic delvings so if any sentence doesn't have an "about" in it just assume it has been said. Depending on various factors such as those below and others, the on PCB propogation delay will be from 10% to 50 % to ???% slower so delays  of say 1 to 2 times typically are seen compared to free space and longer would be no surprise.

There are tables available that give approximate propogationn delays (PDs) dfor various PCB materials and track topology so you can start with a rough guess of

- Delay = 3.5 x k x length_in_mm picoseconds.

  - Where k is a board-material / track / topology velocity factor.

If you have a PCB in hand as you say, them the very very best method available is to measure it under the real world conditions of your choice.

Failing that, the next best method is to use one of the available calculators which perform this task for you. As the answer depends on track width and to some extent, thickness, presence and relationship of other tracks (parallel on same plane, parallel on other side of this layer, nearby, crossing, ... and groundplanes, PCB material, vias and other structures, stubs and components along the way, .............. for a start, then a PCB design program that allows the actual circuit and environment to be modelled is desirable.
 Programs like Altium's PCB suite include this capability as of right.

Finally, you can try to calculate it yourself after having done adequate study. Good luck.

Tracks at frequencies where picoseconds matter will act as "microstrips" - dielectric affected transmission lines.  So ...
 [Wikipedia - Microstrips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstrip)

Also [Wikipedia - Transmission line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line)

---

Useful  [Microstrip Propagation Times - Slower Than We Think](http://www.ultracad.com/mentor/microstrip%20propagation.pdf) - Excellent discussion. He wants to sell you UltraCad's services :-).

[Ultracad home page](http://www.ultracad.com/)

[Various  software PCB design tools from UltraCAD](http://www.ultracad.com/calc.htm) - some free, some not. Free ones are of limited use to you.

---

APPCAD - free ex Agilent RF & Microwave design program.

Well spoken of program  - helps to thing your PCB is a bit of microwave circuitry - which it is.

[APPCAD V3.02 here](http://www.hp.woodshot.com/)

[Olde !!! APPCAD version that runs undr DOS and not windows {fwiw}](http://www.flambda.com/appcad.html)

---

RFSIM99 S parameter simulator. When the easier magic doesn't work
[download here](http://www.eyou.com.au/product/rfsim99/)

---

[Very good user discussion here](http://www.electronicspoint.com/propagation-delay-pcb-traces-t119100.html)

Some gems from above

- So for example, nominally 50
  ohm microstrip on er=5.0 substrate yields about 1.56e8 m/sec
  propagation velocity; er=4.5 makes that 1.64e8, and 4.0 makes it
  1.73e8. (Different calculators will yield slightly different answers,
  but the variation as a percentage should be very close.) So a 20%
  reduction in er made for about a 10.9% increase in velocity.
- That was
  for a trace width that stayed constant; if the trace width is adjusted
  to keep impedance constant, the percentage in propagation velocity is
  slightly less. For stripline (embedded in a constant er), the
  velocity variation over the same er range is about 11.8%.
- Note also that there is some variation in velocity as a function of
  frequency...it's not huge, but it's there.
- It will help a lot if you specify a particular substrate material.
  "FR4" doesn't cut it; "Isola 370HR"

&

- FRF-4 is pretty inconsistent, and its capacitance TC is remarkable, ballpark 950 PPM. If you need tight prop delay spread, you'll need a better laminate.

---

Useful [Fundamentals of SI (Part 2) – Transmission lines](http://blogs.mentor.com/hyperblog/blog/tag/velocity-of-propagation/)
 He essentially concludes that the rule of thumb speed is half light speed or K=2 in my formula.

---

Why you may care [Interesting discussion of PD effect & design with high speed processors](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/app_note/AN1794.pdf)

---

EMC design for high speed PCBs.  Related [here](http://www.icd.com.au/articles/emc.html)

---

Some good refs in thus user discussion [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=206271)

---

$40 book - but what a good title :-)
[High Speed Digital Design: A Handbook of Black Magic - Howard W Johnson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133957241) - author is an acknowledged grand master of the art.

Comment: -1 because OP asked specifically how to *measure* the delay, and your answer only says how to predict it from the geometry and materials.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Can't read first lines apparently. If the answer was not there would this specific question or the S.E. community as a whole be better served? Is the information apposite and relevant **despite** the truth of what you say about its focus? Would you like me to delete it? Is the answer, given its direct applicability and relevance not worth at least a neutral leaving alone instead of a brain dead down voting? [The points for their own sake are irrelevant to me, as should be obvious and as I would hope that you were aware. The principle isn't].

Comment: This could be a good answer to a different question. But my feeling is that the massive wall of text, especially coming from a top answerer, is discouraging to others who might have an answer that's more on topic.

Comment: @ThePhoton - as long as they can handle line one they should be OK :-). It may very well be that after they have tackled the reality of the practical that they will find the underlying theoretical or rule of thumb usual either good enough and/or downright relief inducing. Maybe not. Said TA's can also get discouraged when massive walls of nontheless apposite text get dis'd so lightly. It does help make it less likely that good answers will be available on future occasions. But only a little so :-).

Answer (score 0):

Use good signal source (function generator) and good sampling or real time scope together with two good active, correctly calibrated, well matched to the trace probes and you are good to go. The precision that you are asking for is well within higher end test equipment capabilities (read as both relatively new and expensive).

Comment: Note that 1/pS = ~THz

Comment: @clabacchio - Guys in the lab do such measurements on the daily basis. Note that modern specs for very high speed serial links call for such measurements. For example one standard that I am working with call for skew between lines of no more then few pico seconds (lines within differential transmission pair).

Comment: I don't deny that, but "good" has to be defined with numbers for this kind of measurements :)